# Consider a function $f(x, y) = Ax^5 + Bx^4y + Cx^3y^2 + Dx^2y^3 + xy^4 − y^5$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Consider a function $f(x, y) = Ax^5 + Bx^4y + Cx^3y^2 + Dx^2y^3 + xy^4 − y^5$
> where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are unspecified real numbers. Determine the values of
> $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ such that $f(x,y)$ satisfies $f_{xx}(x,y) + f_{yy}(x,y) = 0$

What I did so far, I took double derivative of x and y:

> $f_{xx}(x,y) = 20Ax^3+12Bx^2y+6Cxy^2+2Dy^3$
>
> $f_{yy}(x,y) = 2Cx^3+6Dx^2y+12xy^2-20y^3$

How can I satisfies $f_{xx}(x,y) + f_{yy}(x,y) = 0$? There are no terms that cancels, subtracts or add.

Comment: If you use LaTeX formatting, your question will be much easier to read and likely attract more answers. Just a friendly FYI.

Comment: Actually terms do cancel... $2Dy^3 - 20y^3 = 0$ so $D = 10$ and so on...

Comment: Thanks Everyone, You all are awesome. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add up and you get

$[20A+2C]x^3 + [12B+6D]x^2y + [6C+12]xy^2 + [2D-20]y^3=0$

So

$D = 10$

$C = -2$

$B = -5$

$A = \frac{1}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

You've calculated $f_{xx},f_{yy}$. Now, note that $f_{xx}+f_{yy}$ is a polynomial, so $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ for all $x,y$ if and only if all the coefficients are zero. This will give you a set of conditions on $A,B,C,D$.